Divergence of the Riemann Zeta function

Consider the equation  $\displaystyle\zeta\left(s\right) \Gamma\left(s\right) =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{s - 1}}{{\rm e}^{u} - 1}
{\rm d}u$.
This integral equals
$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{u}{{\rm e}^{u} - 1}\,u^{s - 2}\,{\rm d}u$.
Substituting $\displaystyle\frac{u}{{\rm e}^u - 1} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{B_{n}u^{n}}{n!}$ where $B_{n}$ is the $n$th Bernoulli number:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{B_{n}u^{n + s - 2}}{n!}\,{\rm d}u =
\left.\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{B_{n}}{n!\left(n + s - 1\right)}\,u^{n + s - 1}
\right\vert_{0}^{\infty}
$$
Regardless of the value of $s$ here, it seems that a lot of the terms are going to diverge to infinity. How can this sum therefore be finite ?.

What have i done wrong ?.

How is the interchange of sum and intergral justified?

Also, how do you justify $$\lim_{u\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n(u)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lim_{u\to\infty}f_n(u)?$$

The problem is the term-wise Mellin transform $$\mathcal{M}u\leftu^{n-1}\right=\int_0^{\infty } u^{n-1} u^{s-1} , du=2 \pi  \delta (i (n+s-1))$$ doesn't converge in the usual sense, rather it only converges in a distributional sense. The substitution $$\frac{1}{e^u-1}=\sum\limits{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n u}$$ is a correct way of evaluating the Mellin transform of $\frac{1}{e^u-1}$.

Also, I believe the radius of convergence of $$\frac{u}{e^u-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n, u^n}{n!}$$ is $2 \pi$.
